# Dimension of the kernel. of powers of an operator

Tags: linear-transformations

I am trying to solve the below problem for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and a linear map $T: V \to V$.

> Prove that for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, the following inequality holds:
> $$
> \dim \text{ker}(T^m) - \dim \text{ker}(T^{m-1}) \geq \dim \text{ker}(T^{m+1}) - \dim \text{ker}(T^m).
> $$

I tried to use the rank-nullity theorem a few times for each. of the maps $T^m$, $T^{m-1}$, and $T^{m+1}$. That tells me:
\begin{align*}
\dim V &= \dim \text{ker}(T^{m-1}) + \dim \text{Range}(T^{m-1}) \\ 
\dim V &= \dim \text{ker}(T^{m}) + \dim \text{Range}(T^{m}) \\ 
\dim V &= \dim \text{ker}(T^{m+1}) + \dim \text{Range}(T^{m+1}) \\ 
\end{align*}
I can rearrange to isolate dimension of the kernels:
\begin{align*}
\dim \text{ker}(T^{m-1}) = \dim V - \dim \text{Range}(T^{m-1}) \\ 
\dim \text{ker}(T^{m}) = \dim V - \dim \text{Range}(T^{m}) \\ 
\dim \text{ker}(T^{m+1}) = \dim V - \dim \text{Range}(T^{m+1}) \\ 
\end{align*}
I also know that if $Tv = 0$, then $T^2 v = 0$ and so on, so:
$$
\text{ker}(T^{m-1}) \subset \text{ker}(T^m) \subset \text{ker}(T^{m+1})
$$
which means that $\dim \text{ker}(T^{m-1}) \leq \dim \text{ker}(T^m) \leq \dim \text{ker}(T^{m+1})$. It's also true that If $T^2 v = w$, then $T(Tv) = w$, so the range subspaces are nested in the opposite direction:
$$
\text{Range}(T^{m-1}) \supset \text{Range}(T^m) \supset \text{Range}(T^{m+1}),
$$
so $\dim \text{Range}(T^{m+1}) \leq \dim \text{Range}(T^m) \leq \text{Range}(T^{m-1})$.

After many attempts, I cannot find a way to string together all of these facts to come up with the above inequality.

Comment: Did you consider trying to prove it when $m=1$ first? It simplify out the algebra but still guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @Tulip Ok, I tried it. If $m = 1$, $T^{m-1} = I$, which has a zero-dimensional kernel, so the inequality is reduced to $2 \dim \text{ker}(T) \geq \dim \text{ker}(T^2)$. I know that $\dim \text{ker} (T) \leq \dim \text{ker}(T^2)$, but I can't figure out how adding on one more factor of $\dim \text{ker}(T)$ on the left flips the inequality sign.

Comment: Why are you tagging this "proof-explanation", if you do not have a proof that you want explained? The tag descriptions says, in its entirety: "This tag is for readers who ask for explanation and clarification of some steps of a particular proof." Do you believe this is an accurate description of what you are asking?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I apologize for using the wrong tag. I should have read this more closely before posting the question. Should I only use the "linear transformations" tag?

Comment: You should only use appropriate tags. All appropriate tags, no inappropriate ones.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, start with the case $m=1$, we need to show that $$ 2\dim\ker(T) \ge \dim\ker(T^2).$$

From the rank nullity theorem, we know that
$$\dim(V)=\dim T(V) + \dim\ker(T)=\dim T^2(V)+\dim \ker(T^2)\tag{1}$$

Next, use the rank nullity theorem on the space $T(V)$ (with the transformation $T$)
$$\dim(T(V))= \dim T^2(V) +\color{red} {\dim\left(\ker(T)\cap T(V)\right)}$$

Now, plug this equation back into $(1)$ and cancel $\dim T^2(V)$ out to get

$$\dim\ker(T^2)= \dim\ker(T)+ \dim\left(\ker(T)\cap T(V)\right)\le 2\dim\ker(T)$$
which is the desired result. The case $m>1$ can be handled similarly.

---

Explaining the term in red: Let $\tilde{T}:T(V)\to T(V)$ be the restriction of $T$ to $T(V)\subset V$, then by the rank-nullity theorem, we have $$\dim(T(V))= \dim\tilde{T}(T(V)) +\dim\ker(\tilde{T}),$$
but $\tilde{T}(T(V))=T^2(V)$ and $\ker(\tilde{T})=\ker(T)\cap T(V)$.

---

Comment: +1, much simpler than using Jordan form.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$J_{\lambda, k} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\ & \lambda & 1 \\ & & \lambda & 1 \\ &&&\ddots & \ddots \\ &&&&\lambda & 1 \\ &&&&&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$
denote the Jordan block for an eigenvalues $\lambda$ and size $k$.

---

When $\lambda = 0$, by calculating powers of $J_{0, k}$ you can show that $$\dim \ker J_{0, k}^m = \begin{cases} m & 1 \le m \le k \\ k & m > k\end{cases}.$$ Thus, the inequality $\dim \ker J_{0, k}^m - \dim \ker J_{0,k}^{m-1} \ge \dim \ker J_{0,k}^{m+1} - \dim \ker J_{0,k}^m$ is true since it is either $1 \ge 1$ or $1 \ge 0$ or $0 \ge 0$.

---

When $\lambda \ne 0$, then $\dim \ker J_{0, k}^m = 0$ for all $m$, so $\dim \ker J_{0, k}^m - \dim \ker J_{0,k}^{m-1} \ge \dim \ker J_{0,k}^{m+1} - \dim \ker J_{0,k}^m$ is always $0 \ge 0$.

---

In general, there is a basis for which the matrix of $T$ is a block diagonal matrix with Jordan blocks like $\begin{bmatrix}J_{\lambda_1, k_1} \\ & \ddots \\ && J_{\lambda_n, k_n}\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\dim \ker T^m = \sum_{i=1}^n \dim \ker J_{\lambda_i, k_i}^m$, so you can show the desired inequality holds by looking at each block separately.